# Upload Fast Report(fr3) file type in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am working in a codeigniter's file upload page in one of my projects. I am not able to upload Fast Report(.fr3) file types. I am using the following code

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'fr3';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

What should I do to upload these types of files through codeigniter. I could not find a solution in codeigniter documentation. Thanks In Advance..

Comment: What is the exact error you see?

Comment: The file with fr3 types are not saved